# Docker Swarm managers acting nodes?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I've created setup with 3 swarm managers and 3 nodes.

You e can see below that in the case with 3 masters and 3 workers actually I have **3 managers and 6 nodes**. Is it idea that managers are also capable to run containers, not just workers? Am I missing something in the setup or this is intended to work  as it is now?

when I execute docker info command, I am getting this output:

```
ubuntu@manager3:~$ docker info
Containers: 4
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 23
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: overlay bridge host null
Swarm: active
 NodeID: 9uv3xhwzibx52xghpsa0sp3f7
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 04r095rvj6b4i7ygbnr2quo9e
 **Managers: 3
 Nodes: 6**
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot interval: 10000
  Heartbeat tick: 1
  Election tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat period: 5 seconds
 CA configuration:
  Expiry duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 172.100.0.23
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-92-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 992.5 MiB
Name: manager3
ID: MUXB:GUNV:HIDO:APRJ:S2JU:763E:QSOL:2554:EZJL:L4OI:6TS5:RD7O
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

when I create some services to run on swarm cluster:

`docker service create --replicas=3 --name redis redis:latest`

Some of them will run on managers, some on workers. That's confusing me.

if I create more services

`docker service create --replicas=6 --name redis redis:latest`

they will run on all machines in cluster. increasing even more will start failing due to port collision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node (host) running as a swarm manager isn't different than one running as a worker as far as running services is concerned. It's perfectly fine to have a 3 node swarm with a swarm manager on each one (and no worker).

As for port collision, you need to specify the public port (on the host) when you create the service. Eg:

```
docker create service --name redis --publish 8080:80 --replicas 5 redis:latest
```

Docker will then load balance any incoming request to port 8080 on **any of the nodes** to one of the redis containers on the cluster (not necessarily on the same node as the incoming request)

Comment: So there is no possiblity to restrict managers to run services? One more question: If I run some microservices with Consul annotated in code for service discovery which and I have consul agent in --net=host mode, is there any chance that microservices from overlay network find & route traffic from/to --net=host network? :$

Comment: @DušanŠušić it's possible to configure manager to not run containers. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/admin_guide/#/run-manager-only-nodes

Comment: As @Mark O'Connor writes, you can specify that managers do not act as workers. You can also use constraints when creating/updating a service to specify which nodes they run on. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#/specify-service-constraints.

As for your other question, create a new stackoverflow post otherwise others won't find it. The question is not very clear either. Try to include details, code example.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Mark O'Connor answer is:

> By default manager nodes also act as a worker nodes.

Manager can be drained and stay "only" manager, so you will execute this command to manager stops being worker:

```
docker node update --availability drain *manager_name*
```